# How should I handle ajax/jquery POSTS with django's CSRF, assuming nobody has cookies enabled?

Tags: ajax, django, json, csrf, reddit

Django requires it so ajax posts to the server require CSRF protection. But CSRF requires cookies to be enabled or django will 404 the request. Assuming that nobody has cookies enabled, how should I handle my ajax posts? I don't want to use the @exempt_csrf decorator for security issues.

(Not sure if csrf protection is even needed for what i'm doing, the ajax requests are just for upvoting and downvoting posts like on this website)

Thank you guys!

Comment: Why would you assume nobody has CSRF enabled? The huge overwhelming majority of users leave it enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's in-built CSRF protection will not work without cookies.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-it-works

You need to roll your own CSRF protection for these views, if you decide it is required. Or use something like https://github.com/mozilla/django-session-csrf (per Abid A's answer, the session framework require cookies so this won't help in your case.)

Comment: Well if CSRF really can't work without cookies, is it ok if my ajax post's simply have no CSRF protection? The ajax posts are for upvoting and downvoting threads.

Comment: That's up to you!  Abid A makes a good point that the session framework requires cookies so the django-session-csrf would not help you.

Answer (score 0):

I will write as @Tomasz wrote with small change.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/myurl',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name="csrf_token"]').val(),
        mydata: 'myparam'
    }
});
```

If you are using jquery.

Comment: It works when cookies are enabled but not disabled once again. For the record, the django CSRF ajax cookie header is present so that shouldn't be an issue, sorry i'm a beginner.

Comment: Ah, I think it has nothing to do with cookies. It will send csrf_token as a GET or POST parameter, depending on your way to send.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are required for Django's CSRF protection to work.

You can get the details here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-it-works

Keep in mind, Django's entire session framework is also cookie-based so if you have a lot of users who disable their cookies, you're going to run into additional problems - for example, with authentication.